# Prepend select box in text field form rails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

Is there an easy way to prepend a select box or dropdown box with input to a text field in rails? I am using Twitter bootstrap, and I am able to get the select box added in, but styling is not working so well. So far I have tried two things:

1.

```
  <%= f.text_field :var, label: "Test Box",  class: 'form-control',
                    placeholder: "Test Stuff", prepend: f.select(:options,
                    options_for_select(...) %>
```

This gets the overall bootstrap styling to the select box, but for some reason it is reading `:options` as a label, and I can't get it to assign anything to it.

2.

```
  <%= f.text_field :var, label: "Test Box",  class: 'form-control',
                    placeholder: "Test Stuff", prepend: f.select_without_bootstrap(:options,
                    options_for_select(...) %>
```

This gets the select box in there correctly, but it is not styled (hence the `without_bootstrap` and I am having a difficult time styling it.

So I am wondering if there is a better way to do this, or if this is even a possibility in general? I know I could also add it as a separate field entirely and just align it next to it, but I am trying to do it into the same field. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

What is the reason to do it via the prepend, and not in the template directly?

```
<%= f.select :options ...
<%= f.text_field :var ...
```

Comment: cosmetic desire :). I know I can do it that way as well, I am playing around with a different look.